# Converting date format in R

Tags: r

```
head(df2)

           PointForecast     Lo 80    Hi 80      Lo 95    Hi 95   Region1
2017.0329       3.745038 0.8042195 6.685857 -0.7525558 8.242632 Ahmedabad
2017.0356       3.745038 0.7976683 6.692408 -0.7625749 8.252651 Ahmedabad
2017.0384       3.745038 0.7911317 6.698944 -0.7725718 8.262648 Ahmedabad
2017.0411       3.745038 0.7846095 6.705467 -0.7825467 8.272623 Ahmedabad
2017.0438       3.745038 0.7781017 6.711974 -0.7924996 8.282576 Ahmedabad
2017.0466       3.745038 0.7716080 6.718468 -0.8024307 8.292507 Ahmedabad
```

Here the rownames are in my df2 as 2017.0356,...............
Here I need to convert 2017.0329 ,2017.0356, ..............this into year-month-day format

Comment: Which date is `2017.0356?`

Comment: What is the current format? is `2017.0329` 2017 + 0.0329 years?

Answer (score 2):

```r
library(lubridate)

#I have added time as well because row names can't have duplicate values.
row.names(df2) <- format(date_decimal(as.numeric(row.names(df2))), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%s")
```

Output is:

```
                            Forecast     Lo.80    Hi.80      Lo.95    Hi.95   Region1
2017-01-13 00:01:1484246534 3.745038 0.8042195 6.685857 -0.7525558 8.242632 Ahmedabad
2017-01-13 23:01:1484331681 3.745038 0.7976683 6.692408 -0.7625749 8.252651 Ahmedabad
2017-01-15 00:01:1484419982 3.745038 0.7911317 6.698944 -0.7725718 8.262648 Ahmedabad
2017-01-16 00:01:1484505129 3.745038 0.7846095 6.705467 -0.7825467 8.272623 Ahmedabad
2017-01-16 23:01:1484590276 3.745038 0.7781017 6.711974 -0.7924996 8.282576 Ahmedabad
2017-01-18 00:01:1484678577 3.745038 0.7716080 6.718468 -0.8024307 8.292507 Ahmedabad
```

Sample data:

```
df2 <- structure(list(Forecast = c(3.745038, 3.745038, 3.745038, 3.745038, 
3.745038, 3.745038), Lo.80 = c(0.8042195, 0.7976683, 0.7911317, 
0.7846095, 0.7781017, 0.771608), Hi.80 = c(6.685857, 6.692408, 
6.698944, 6.705467, 6.711974, 6.718468), Lo.95 = c(-0.7525558, 
-0.7625749, -0.7725718, -0.7825467, -0.7924996, -0.8024307), 
    Hi.95 = c(8.242632, 8.252651, 8.262648, 8.272623, 8.282576, 
    8.292507), Region1 = c("Ahmedabad", "Ahmedabad", "Ahmedabad", 
    "Ahmedabad", "Ahmedabad", "Ahmedabad")), .Names = c("Forecast", 
"Lo.80", "Hi.80", "Lo.95", "Hi.95", "Region1"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("2017.0329", 
"2017.0356", "2017.0384", "2017.0411", "2017.0438", "2017.0466"
))
```

Comment: Hi sir, i used the above command but i got below error                              > rownames(df2) <- format(date_decimal(as.numeric(row.names(df2))), "%d-%b-%Y")
Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = value) : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
In addition: Warning message:
non-unique values when setting 'row.names': ‘01-Apr-2017’, ‘01-Aug-2017’, ‘01-Dec-2017’, ‘01-Feb-2017’, ‘01-Jan-2018’, ‘01-Jul-2017’, ‘01-Jun-2017’, ‘01-Mar-2017’, ‘01-May-2017’, ‘01-Nov-2017’, ‘01-Oct-

Comment: That's the reason I added time along with date in my updated answer. Above error message says that you can't have duplicate row names and it's pretty logical to have unique row names. If you want to convert it into the format you want then you'll have to add time to it (see the format `%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%s` in my answer)